# Bernoulli random variables in c++

Tags: c++, random

What is the easiest way to get a Bernoulli distributed random variable in C++? I 
I have a non-const p.
p starts from 0, getting `p+=0.01` , until `p=1`. ("for" loop) I have this idea:

declare int aray in size of 100, intilized with zeros. evrey time the p gets `+0.01`, I change one zero to "1"... and get a random number%100.

is it good?
thanks

Comment: By using one of the already existing [Bernoulli distributions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random#Bernoulli_distributions)?

Comment: Did you try [`std::bernoulli_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/bernoulli_distribution)?

Comment: thanks! I didnt know it exists!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use modern C++ (C++11 or later if possible). You can do this:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd{}; // use to seed the rng 
    std::mt19937 rng{rd()}; // rng

    double p = 0.2; // probability
    std::bernoulli_distribution d(p);

    // generate 5 runs
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        std::cout << d(rng) << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can get a random number between 0 and 1, and calculate the bernoulli random number from it

```
double p = 0.5;
double r = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));
unsigned int br = 0;
if (r >= p) 
   br = 1;
```